# TypeORM - query by values of nested collections

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I have an asset with a group of prices. Looks more or less like this:

```
export class Asset {
  ..
  prices: AssetPrice[];
}
```

Now I would like to get all assets which do not have a price given for today. Equivalent of a simple inner join on price.createdAt

I tried repo method but it doesn't cope well with anything more complex than a simple where.

The database is Postgres

Comment: Is prices a jsonb column or a reference to another table AssetPrice? I believe it's the latter given the mention of inner join but just confirming

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far just to get an idea of what you're looking for given that typeorm has multiple ways of querying